# How can a limit exist if the function isn't defined/doesn't exist at that point?

Tags: limits, continuity

I hope I make sense, but I'm just a little confused and don't understand how a limit can exist at a certain point even if the function itself doesn't (is discontinuous)?

Thank you :)

Comment: If you study the definition of limit (definitions are your friends), you will see that it is carefully stated to *avoid* any dependence on or reference to the evaluation of the function "at" the limiting argument.  So in that sense not having the function defined there is not an obstacle.

Comment: The definition of a limit at a point, never discusses the nature of the  function at the point. If you are still confused, please copy the definition that is in your textbook/has been given to you, and we can clarify it here.

Comment: Because limits is only concerned about its neighborhood behavior. I recommend you read Howard Anton's Calculus.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of a limit is to look at the function in the general neighbourhood of the point at interest, without looking at the point itself. Since you can define a function pretty much arbitrarily, you can do something like this:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}x \mbox{ if } x \neq 13 \\
0 \mbox{ if } x = 13\end{cases}$$

So for this function, $f(3) = 3$, $f(10) = 10$, $f(12.999) = 12.999$, $f(13.0001) = 13.0001$, and $f(13) = 0$. If we calculate the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \rightarrow 13$, then we see the function get closer and closer to equalling 13:

$$\begin{eqnarray} f(12) & = & 12 \\
f(12.9) & = & 12.9 \\
f(12.99) & = & 12.99 \\
f(12.9999999) & = & 12.9999999\end{eqnarray}$$

and so forth. We say that we can always get as close as we want to our function equalling 13 by choosing a value of $x$ close enough to 13. Importantly, *it doesn't matter that $f(13) \neq 13$*. In fact, even if we didn't set a value for $f(13)$, we can still say that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 13}f(x) = 13$ as long as the function is defined in the neighbourhood of $x = 13$.